# Environment or Mediastore?

Tags: android, storage, environment, mediastore

I want to save a picture in my mobile with my application. I have two solutions, both works but I still don't know which is the best one. 
I try with this :

```
File file = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + UUID.randomUUID.toString() + ".jpeg");
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
outputStream.write(bytes);
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
```

And with this :

```
SimpleDateFormat timeStampFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
   "yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss");
    String fileName = "photo_" + timeStampFormat.format(new Date())
    + ".jpg";

    // Metadata
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName);
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Image prise par FormationCamera");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, new Date().getTime());
                    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
Uri taken = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

OutputStream outputStream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(taken);
outputStream.write(bytes);
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
```

So for the first one my URI look like this :

```
/storage/emulated/0/<something>
```

and the second one my URI look like this :

```
content://media/external/images/media
```

So do you know which one is the best solution??

Comment: What are your requirements ?

Comment: I just want to save an image in the most efficient way possible. in the future I will change it to save this picture on a .NET server. and I hate to write some information about it

Comment: depends on your requirement. if you don't have so many requirements and if you'd like a simple solution, go with the first one. simple and short.

Comment: ok I understand, but can I know what allow me each solution ? 
out of pure curiosity